# How do I access all my fancybox galleries from my navigation?

Tags: jquery, onclick, fancybox, gallery, hyperlink

I have quite unique situation. Here is my scenario: My page has several pictures that each launch a fancybox gallery. I would like to access each gallery by clicking the photo and in a seperate link in my navigation bar. So far I have seen an example that allows you to set up the navigation with an "onclick" event which is very helpful however, I want to expand on that and be able to have each link in my navigation be able to access a different gallery from those pictures. The only way I know how to use this feature in fancybox is by using the "rel" attribute but I don't know how to wire that into my onclick event. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a snippet of my current html however, again I can only access the first gallery and I want to be able to design my onclick event so I can tell it which gallery I would like to access.

```
 onclick="$('.gallery').eq(0).trigger('click'); return false;
```

The onclick above allows me to access the 'rel="group2"' gallery but I need each link to access a different 'rel="group#"'

```
</div>
<div>
    <a class="gallery" rel='group3' href="Pictures/FinalPhotos/GG.jpg">
    <img src="Pictures/FinalPhotos/GG.jpg"class="pictures4"  alt="deck"></a>
    <a class="gallery" rel='group3' href="Pictures/DDC/IMG_5577-Rendering.jpg"></a>
    <a class="gallery" rel='group3' href="Pictures/atriumdarkps.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access each gallery from a separated link doing this (directly into the `href` without `onclick` attribute):

```
<a href="javascript:$('[rel=group1]').eq(0).trigger('click'); return false;">access group 1</a>
<a href="javascript:$('[rel=group2]').eq(0).trigger('click'); return false;">access group 2</a>
<a href="javascript:$('[rel=group3]').eq(0).trigger('click'); return false;">access group 3</a>
```

... etc.

Since all elements share the same class `gallery` (but a different `rel` attribute) you can use a single script for all of them

```
$(".gallery").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a6eB8/)**

Comment: JFK Thank you so much! This is going to save my site. I really appreciate it! I would vote up but apparently I require 15 reputation points.